# Globally Replace Old School $PHP_SELF with $SERVER['PHP_SELF'] using sed

Tags: php, sed, oscommerce

Not being an sed expert, I need to replace all instances of the string `$PHP_SELF` with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` globally in a directory.

This is an "old school" osCommerce application that I need to resurrect temporarily for a showcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` doesn't recurse on it's own so you'll need to use another tool for that, `find` is generally the right answer.

Run this in the top-level directory.  `sed` will make a backup of each file it reads with a `.bak` extension (regardless if it actually does a replacement). If you don't want the backup behavior, use `-i` instead of `-i.bak`

I recommend you first try this on a test directory to make sure it meets expectations.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
   sed -i.bak $'s/$PHP_SELF/$_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\']/g' "$file"
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.php" -print0)
```

Comment: For the POST vars,  I was actually successful when I ran `find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/HTTP_POST_VARS/_POST/g' {} \;` but was a bit timid to run `sed`  with the dollar ($) sign.

Comment: Working perfectly! Thanks much!

Comment: The $ and literal single quotes in the match and/or replacement can get tricky. The `bash` solution is to us `$''` which won’t expand $ and let you specify a literal single-quote with `\'`